# What do dot and hash symbols mean in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I feel confused of the dot and hash symbols in the following example:

```
<DIV ID="row">
<DIV ID="c1">              
<Input type="radio" name="testing" id="testing" VALUE="1">testing1
</DIV>
</DIV>
```

Code 1:

```
 $('#row DIV').mouseover(function(){     
    $('#row DIV').addClass('testing');  
    });
```

Code 2

```
  $('.row div').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('testing');
    });​
```

Codes 1 and 2 look very similar, and so it makes me so confused that
when I should use ".row div" to refer to a specific DIV instead of using "#row div" ?

Comment: They're CSS Selectors. Google can help you with those: http://www.google.com/search?q=css+selectors+tutorial

Comment: @DanielPryden i'd argue that recommending a particular tutorial is helpful -- recommending a Google search, not so much.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The hash (#) specifies to select elements by their ID's

The dot (.) specifies to select elements by their classname

You can read more about the selectors here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/

Comment: Additionally, `#` and `.` are the same as they are in CSS.

Answer (score 28):

$('.row') will select any element with `class="row"`

$('#row') will select the element with `id=row`

[Check the jQuery page on selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: And for completeness: `$('row')` will select any `<row>` element.

Answer (score 9):

These are CSS selectors.

The hash symbol `#` means that the element is an ID. So `#row` would match `<div id="row">`.

Alternatively, the dot symbol `.` means the element is a CSS class. So `.row` would match `<div class="row">`.

There is more information over at [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html).

Comment: +1 for pointing out the xref between jQuery and CSS - I'm sure the jQuery authors chose these selectors intentionally to map to the existing standard for CSS.

Comment: jQuery actually uses sizzle which is a css selector engine in javascript: http://sizzlejs.com/

Answer (score 5):

"." refers to a class, while "#" refers to IDs.

```
<table id="table">
    <tr class="odd"></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr class="odd"></tr>
</table>
```

$("#table") would get the full table object, while $(".odd") would get everything with the class "odd". $("tr.odd") would only get table rows with that class.

Answer (score 2):

The `.` specifies a *class* called "row."  The `#` specifies an *id* called "row."