# How to dynamically add and remove maxlength validation by Parsley.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, dynamic, parsley.js

I am using [parsley.js](http://parsleyjs.org/) and I have to dynamically show/hide validation according to the data the user has selected.

I have read this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21867162/how-can-i-dynamically-add-and-remove-form-fields-to-be-validated-by-parsley-js/21885466#21885466) to dynamically add or remove required fields to be validated by parsley, which was helpful.

**But how do I dynamically remove and add the *maxlength* for an input field?**

I have tried the following two options:

```
$('input').attr('data-parsley-maxlength', 'true');
$('input').attr('data-parsley-maxlength', true);
```

But the above gives the following error message:

```
This value is too long. It should have true characters or fewer.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reckon you just need to assign correct value type to the attribute, `data-parsley-maxlength` which is numerical value, see here: http://parsleyjs.org/doc/#validators-overview

> Maxlength #2.0 -->    data-parsley-maxlength="10" --> Validates that the length
>   of a string is not larger than the given limit.

Hope this will fit your need `:)`

Try this:

```
//destroy parsley
$('form').parsley().destroy();

//set required attribute on input to value type
$('input').attr('data-parsley-maxlength', '0');

//reinitialize parsley
$('form').parsley();
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, But, what is the difference in using the # as follows:                                                         `$('input').attr('data-parsley-maxlength', '0');`                           compared to                                                                                                                  `$('#input').attr('data-parsley-maxlength', '0');`                                      Should I be using the # symbol in the parsley code? I think this is where my problem is, but cannot quite figure it out with my code, so I have to ask a really basic question.

Comment: @user1261774 glad it helped; The hash (#) specifies to select elements by their ID's, read here ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860394/what-do-dot-and-hash-symbols-mean-in-jquery and jquery documentation -> http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/ . The `$('input')` means validation on any `<input>` html element.

Comment: @Tats_innit Is reinitializing also necessary when changing the value of an existing `data-parsley-maxlength`?`

Comment: Hiya @awendt I had a quick peek inside parsley, seems like yes at this stage. :) correct me if I am wrong.