# Ajax request not starting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have below html part

```
<div style="display:inline-block" class="seeker">
    <style>h2   {color: white;}</style>
        <form action="">
        <input type="checkbox" class="seek" id=CLOUD name="CLOUD" value="CLOUD"  >CLOUD &emsp;
        <input type="checkbox" class="seek" id=TESTING name="TESTING" value="TESTING"  >TESTING &emsp;
    </form>
</div>
```

and this as part of script

```
<script>
$('.seek').click(function(){
     alert("test");
     /*var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
     var endpoint = '/xyz/pqr/'
     var url = endpoint.concate(value)
     $.get(url, function(data){
         $("#testDIV").html(response);
           });*/
});
```

But on checking the checkbox the ajax call is not triggered any issue with code?

Comment: `#` indicates an ID, but "seek" is a class. Try `$('.seek')`. See [What do dot and hash symbols mean in JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860394/what-do-dot-and-hash-symbols-mean-in-jquery) Also, where are you defining the `id` variable?

Comment: @showdev yes but still it doesn't works

Comment: Regarding your edit, [I can't reproduce the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/mdbbux3q/). Can you [create an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help demonstrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.seek').on('change', function() {
   var checkedValues = $('.seek:checked').map(function(){
     return $(this).val();
   }).get();
   console.log("Changed: ", this.value, "to", this.checked)
   console.log(checkedValues);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display:inline-block" class="seeker">
    <style>h2   {color: white;}</style>
        <form action="">
        <input type="checkbox" class="seek" id=CLOUD name="CLOUD" value="CLOUD"  >CLOUD &emsp;
        <input type="checkbox" class="seek" id=TESTING name="TESTING" value="TESTING"  >TESTING &emsp;
    </form>
</div>
```

You should use the `change` event, not `click` for checkboxes:

```
$('.seek').on('change', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     alert("test");
});
```

Comment: Oh geez, derped out hard on that one...changing my answer

Comment: @pkm It would be nice to know what solved your problem. Several people have show that your code is working, even with a `click` event. What was wrong and what did you change that helped?

Comment: @showdev
i was new to ajax  so went through some tutorials and found the skeleton should look like this and same suggested by others

$(function(){
$('.seek').on('change', function() {

});
});

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I noticed is that you are using $('#seek'). seek is a class so  you should be using $('.seek') to select it.

jQuery uses the standard "CSS" selectors. so

```
# = ID
. = Class
[name='foo'] = Name
ect
```

Comment: $.get is an Ajax shorthand method. Edit - beat me to it.

Comment: Ok at what point is it breaking now? I'm guessing the click is at least firing? Assuming it is you setting the html to response and not data?

Comment: i think thats the breaking point, click is not getting fire .....do i need to add onclick event pointing to this function or anything?

Comment: It should at least be firing off the alert I have it on this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mudwy1cn/ Have you checked your console for any errors? (JQuery missing maybe?)

Comment: i  have 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  and jquery-3.1.0.min.js already present in my html page anything else we need ?

Comment: Not that can I think off no. Are there any errors in the console when you press the checkboxes? If not could you make a fiddle when the exact code you have please. (Because as you can see in my fiddle the click should at least fire)

Answer (score 0):

`$.get` in your post is within commented block, wrapped with `/**/`, just remove comment

Comment: i am not getting alert also, so i commented it

Comment: updated http://plnkr.co/edit/HoXBRapTmh4T9yrwFinf?p=preview to send fetch ajax as well